# Issue with hp-health-10.50-1826.38.rhel6.x86_64 rpm package in customized version of Linux

Tags: linux, unix, redhat, rpm

I am using a customized rh6 version and have a script hpasmxld_reset.sh that is obtained after installing the RPM -> hp-health-10.50-1826.38.rhel6.x86_64.The script hpasmxld_reset.sh display errors on execution.

There is an update/advance version to hp-health-10.50-1826.38.rhel6.x86_64, it is hp-health-10.60-1833.32.rhel7.x86_64.rpm .I want to check if the hpasmxld_reset.sh is fixed in this later 10.60 version .

My query is if I install hp-health-10.60-1833.32.rhel7.x86_64.rpm on an rh6 machine then would that function appropriately or not ? What should be kept in mind before installing a pkg that has a version above than the present version of the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't be able to install it, since it is the wrong distro. You *should* be able to download it and extract all the files with `rpm2cpio file.rpm | cpio -div` and then you'll have a copy of the new script file to compare to the old one.